# Single/subpixel gap of fixed navbar on iOS Safari (iPhone 13) when scrolling

Tags: html, css, safari, tailwind-css, mobile-safari

I've seen this issue appear on other popular websites as well. There's a subpixel gap between the the top navbar and the status bar when scrolling, where you can see the underlying content. No issues on desktop browsers, just Safari on my iPhone 13.

The div in question is set to "fixed top-0". I'm using tailwindcss.

`<div id="mobile-menu" class="w-full h-11 flex items-center lg:hidden bg-black-50 fixed top-0">`

[The gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4D6M.jpg)

I've noticed this issue on the official Bootstrap fixed navbar example (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/navbar-fixed/) as well. It happens after you hit the hamburger icon:

[Gap on Bootstrap fixed navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AyyZ.jpg)

I've tried setting top to a negative number with no luck. There's still a gap.

Any ideas?